# CodeIgniter AJAX: POST not working, GET works fine

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Fiddling inside CodeIgniter and trying to get a grip on it all as I've never worked with AJAX before.

For some reason, my AJAX is working perfectly when I use the GET method, but if I switch it over to the POST method, it stops working.

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.love').click(function(event) {

        $.ajax({

            type: 'GET',
            url: base_url + '/ajax/love_forum_post',
            data: { post_id: 2, user_id: 1, ajax: 1 },

        });

        return false;

    });

});
```

And my CONTROLLER:

```
function love_forum_post()

{

    $post_id = $this->input->get('post_id');
    $user_id = $this->input->get('user_id');
    $is_ajax = $this->input->get('ajax');

    if ($is_ajax)

    {

        $this->load->model('forums_model');
        $this->forums_model->add_love($post_id, $user_id);

    }

    // If someone tries to access the AJAX function directly.

    else

    {

        redirect('', 'location');

    }

}
```

If I switch the type to 'POST' inside my JS and then catch it on the other end with $this->input->post() it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I have tested your code in 2 scenarios:
first - without csrf protection, and I see no reason for your code not to run properly.
To be able to test it easier, append $.ajax call with success response.
Something like this

```
success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
            }
```

And add response to your love_forum_post method.

```
echo print_r($this->input->post(), true);
```

This would give you clean view of what it going on in your method.

In my installation everything works just fine.

Second scenario is with csrf protection.
In this case add new param to your post object.

```
<?php if ($this->config->item('csrf_protection') === true) : ?>
            post_data.<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?> = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>'; 
<?php endif ?>
```

This would make CI accept post from this url.

Hopefuly it would help.
Cheers

Comment: Yeah, sweet. The issue was I had enabled CSRF protection. How would I pass the CSRF token and catch it remembering that I don't have an actual form in action here? It's just an anchor tag processing the action.

Comment: Never tried that. Check Security library in CI. There are not so much methods, so there must be a way to add it no mather of method used there (GET in your case)

Answer (score 1):

By any chance you have csrf_protection enabled?

If yes you need to send the token and the value key as post parameter along with post request.

Comment: Yes. I had CSRF protection enabled. It works when I disable it. How do I pass the token to my controller etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
$post_data = $_POST;
```

and print the post data using this

```
print_r($post_data);die();
```

and you can see there if you catch the post data;

Gudluck!!